# Render time triples after updating to 2.82 from 2.81

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I just re-rendered a project I'm working on after updating to 2.82 from 2.81 and my render time looks to have tripled after the update. I checked my render settings in the project as well as the render device settings in my preferences and nothing seems to have changed. I can't remember all the places I ticked boxes to optimize my render times as I'm pretty new to Blender, so I'm wondering if there's something else I should look at or any likely culprits?

FYI I'm rendering using Cycles, 500 samples, max total bounces at 4 with GPU Compute selected under Scene settings and CUDA (geforce + intel cpu) selected under preferences. I'm using the detailed denoise information in my denoise node on the compositing screen.